# getActivity () undefined for Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to start a simple background service on an android app
but it seems that in my "startBckgrdSrvice(View v)" , "getActivity()" is 
not defined.

I've already tried to use Activity.this or FrontPage.this but neither of those classes 
had what I am looking for.
Is there somebody who can give me a clue ?

I am using android-studio IDE.

package com.example.leeloo.chut;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FrontPage extends Activity {

    public static final String activate_msg = "Activate";
    public static final String deactivate_msg = "Deactivate";

    private PendCall mbckgrdService;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_page);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.front_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void startBckgrdSrvice(View v){

        CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.activateChkBox);
        if(chkBox.getText().toString().compareTo(activate_msg)==0)
            chkBox.setText(FrontPage.deactivate_msg);
        else {
            chkBox.setText(FrontPage.activate_msg);

            mbckgrdService = new Intent()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: clu: learn java, then learn android API, please show us in documentation where on hell is stated that Activity class has getActivity method... also i do not see the getActivity call in code that you provided(need more downvotes)

Comment: Please mention exactly what are you 'looking for' ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html. I was following this tutorial and I wanted to create my intent in "startBckgrdSrvice()" method, by calling mbckgrdService = new Intent(getActivity(),MyClass.class);

Comment: download the sample ... it is called from Fragment  ... inside startBckgrdSrvice just use `this`

Comment: Thanks you very much. I also had to change my variable "mbckgrdService" to an object of "Intent" class.

Comment: What do you want to do after you call `getActivity()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `PendCall extends Service`, you can try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PendCall.class);
startService(intent);
```

Note that since `startBckgrdSrvice()` is a method inside a class which extends Activity, `this` is a reference to an `Activity` object, so you don't need to call `getActivity()` (which is only available for `Fragment`s). You can also call `startService()` directly since it is a method from `Activity`.

I strongly suggest that you learn about some Java basics, especially inheritance.

Comment: I know how to use Java. I am just having a bad time trying to understand how android do manage that code.

Comment: @BambBakangTonjé Then you need to familiarize yourself with the [Official Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/index.html), especially [the Javadocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) which will clarify what methods are available in each class.